# Rye bread in bread machine - crust very rough on top

Tags: baking, yeast

This is what I'm using for my rye bread in the bread machine. Overall it's tasty and rises okay, but the top sinks a little bit, and is really rough.

```
1 ⅓ warmish water 
1.5 cups regular flour  
1.5 cups rye flour 
1 tablespoon fennel  
1 teaspoon salt
1 teaspoon yeast
```

I'm not using a heatlamp, the bread machine model is the
Breadman 2 lb Professional Bread Maker, Stainless Steel, BK1050S (about a month old). The temperature in the house now probably ranges from 67 to 69. I have it on the regular white bread setting in the bread machine.

Any thoughts? Here's a photo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/U802v.jpg

Comment: It looks like it rose too much.  Which is really surprising, given the small amount of yeast.  Are you doing anything else special?  Putting it under a heat lamp?  What temp is it where you have the bread machine?  And what model is it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, FuzzyChef. I put clarifications in the original.

Comment: OK, that's really wierd then.  Because the photo totally looks like overproofing, but I can't imagine why it would be overproofing; if anything, with the dark flours and low yeast I'd expect underproofing.  So ... NFI.

Comment: Some bread machines are great at overproofing @FuzzyChef. Less sophisticated ones work to time rather than using sensors to track proofing. The only bread machine I ever had overproofed everything so badly I had to reduce the yeast in all their own recipes by half!

Comment: that raises a good question: Sylvia, does this machine work fine making other kinds of bread?

Comment: Yes it does, I use this recipe all the time, same cycle. 1 cup warm water, 
2 cups regular flour , 1 cup whole wheat flour, 1 teaspoon salt, 1 teaspoon yeast, 2 tablespoon oil. Turns out great, nice rounded smooth top.